# swift 3: NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift

Использую этот код для проигрывания аудио. Проблема в том, что из-за этой строчки `RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)` устройство сильно греется. Как это исправить?

Полный код:

```
@IBAction func playAudio(sender: AnyObject) {
    if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
        audioPlayer.play()
        slider.maximumValue = Float(audioPlayer.duration)
        slider.value = 0.0
        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
    } else {
        audioPlayer.pause()
        playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

func updateTime() {
let currentTime = Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
let minutes = currentTime/60
let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
timeElapsed.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Жарко ему от этой строчки? :) Или вы все-таки будете хоть немного конкретизировать возникающие проблемы, наверно нагрузка на процессор высокая, от того и нагрев?
Код тоже анализируйте, интервал 0.0 это практически while (true) {} что нагрузит одно из ядер процессора почти на 100%.

Answer (score 1):

можно также использовать в Swift не NSTimer a GСD-шный и более Swift-style вариант
где то в вашем классе объявите свойство

```
var timer:DispatchSourceTimer?
```

если стартуете новую мелодию, переинициализируйте его

```
timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()
timer?.scheduleRepeating(deadline: .now(), interval: .seconds(1) )
timer?.setEventHandler {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  // ваш код для обновления времени проигрывания на UI      
                    }
}
```

в обработчике кнопки Play/Stop
если хотите запустить
    timer?.resume()

если остановить совсем

```
timer?.cancel()
```

если поставить на паузу

```
timer?.suspend()
```